# Library for existential type wrappers

Tags: haskell, gadt

Lets say I've got the following:

```
data T a

f :: a -> (exists t. T t)
g :: T b -> c

h :: a -> c
h = g . f
```

As I know, the type signature for `f` is not valid Haskell. I can instead do this though:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data T a

data ExistsTA where
  ExistsTA :: T a -> ExistsTA

f :: a -> ExistsTA
g :: T b -> c

h :: a -> c
h x = case (f x) of ExistsTA x' -> g x'
```

Which compiles fine. I was wondering, is there a library that generalises the creation of the `ExistsTA` data type (perhaps takes `T` as a parameter), or do I have to roll my own everytime I want to do this (which is not a big deal, just don't want to reinvent the wheel if I don't need too).

In particular, for my application, I would also like wrappers in this form:

```
data C where
  C1 :: C
  ...

data D (a :: C) where
  D1 a :: D
  ...

data T (d :: D) a

f :: T (D1 C1) a -> exists c. T (D1 c) a
```

Answer (score 3):

I dunno whether this is in a library anywhere, but I like to use the following general-purpose existential:

```
data Ex f = forall a. Ex (f a)
```

With `PolyKinds` `Ex` can existentially wrap up the parameter of any type `f :: k -> *`. How general-purpose is this? We can manipulate `f` until it's the right shape, and we can build in whatever extra information we need, with a little library of type combinators. Working with general-purpose types like this is a powerful way to program, but often it's simpler just to roll your own.

---

Suppose we want to existentially quantify both halves of a two-parameter type `p`. One can use the following GADT to *uncurry* `p`, turning it from a two-parameter type `k1 -> k2 -> *` into a one-parameter type `(k1, k2) -> *`.

```
data Uncurry p ij where
    Uncurry :: { getUncurry :: p i j } -> Uncurry p '(i, j)
```

Now `Uncurry p` can be existentially wrapped.

```
type ExP p = Ex (Uncurry p)
```

---

Suppose I want to pair up my existentially-wrapped type with some evidence such as a singleton, so that one can recover the existentially quantified index. I'll use the index-respecting product to pair up two functors `f` and `g`:

```
newtype (f :*: g) i = f i :*: g i
```

If, say, `f` is a GADT, pattern-matching on the `f`-half of the pair will tell you about `g`'s index. Now, `f :*: g` has the right kind to be existentially wrapped.

```
type ExPair f g = Ex (f :*: g)
```

In practice you might write `ExPair Sing f` to pair up `f` with a singleton.

---

Suppose I need the aforementioned evidence in constraint form. I can replace `Sing` from above with the following type which reifies an instance dictionary for `c a` as a (visible) runtime value:

```
data Dict1 c a where
    Dict1 :: c a => Dict1 c a
```

(or you could use [the `constraints` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.9/docs/Data-Constraint.html): `newtype Dict1 c a = Dict1 { getDict1 :: Dict (c a) }`.) Now I just need to set the left-hand part of my pair to be `Dict1 c`:

```
type ExDictPair c f = ExPair (Dict1 c) f
```

So you might write `ExDictPair SingI f` to package up an implicit singleton.

---

Suppose the thing I need to existentially quantify is at a higher kind, eg `* -> *`. (I might want to talk about "some instance of `Monad` containing an `Int`".) `Ex` is poly-kinded, but it only existentially quantifies the right-most parameter of its argument. So we need the `* -> *` part of the type to be the last argument of our datatype. I can write a type combinator for that too:

```
newtype RApp a f = RApp { getRApp :: f a }

type SomeMonadAppliedToInt = ExDictPair Monad (RApp Int)
```